# How to install a third party apps only to a specific site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am using sharepoint online would want to add an 3rd party app to a specific  site collection. I was able to do it. But i dont want the reference of that or show up on add an apps -> Apps you can add.

Comment: Sounds like a great use case for Site Collection app catalog: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog

Comment: Something you can find helpful here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108256/app-in-app-catalog-only-available-in-specific-sitecollection

Comment: so we will have to make use of powershell to do this.